# Don't understand while ValueError is being raised

Tags: python, regex, slice

I am trying to clean text in the following format:

`['The first chunk of text \n 123 the stats I want (25% the percentage I want) \n The Second chunk of text \n 456 the second stats I want (50% the second percentage I want) \n The third chunk of text \n 789 the third stats I want (75% the third percentage) \n The fourth chunk of text \n 101 The fourth stats (100% the fourth percentage) \n'`]

Into the following format: 
[image]

I have tried the following code:

```
def cleanData(data):
    first_line, second_line = data[0].split("\n")[:2]
    print(first_line)

    digit_match = re.search('\d+(?![\d%])', second_line)
    if digit_match:
        print(digit_match.group())

    percent_match = re.search('\d+%', second_line)
    if percent_match:
        print(percent_match.group())
```

Which works fine for the first instance but cannot seem to get it to work for all instances. I keep getting `ValueError: not enough values to unpack`
 - any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

1. Split the lines in your `data`

   ```
   In [14]: lines = data[0].splitlines()
   ```
2. Use the `zip(iter, iter)` recipe to group the data into pairs of `(text, stats)`

   ```
   In [15]: it = iter(lines)
   In [16]: pairs = zip(it, it)
   ```
3. Use a nested list comprehension with `re.findall` to get the numbers from the 2nd part

   ```
   In [17]: [(a,b,c) for (a, (b, c)) in ((A, re.findall(r"\d+", B)) for A, B in pairs)]
   Out[17]: 
   [('The first chunk of text ', '123', '25'),
    (' The Second chunk of text ', '456', '50'),
    (' The third chunk of text ', '789', '75'),
    (' The fourth chunk of text ', '101', '100')]
   ```

Note: This assumes that those two numbers are the only numeric parts in the second part of the pairs. If this is not the case, you could use a variant of your `re.search` expressions in the list comprehension.

```
In [32]: [(A, re.search(r"(\d+).*\((\d+%).*\)", B).groups()) for A, B in pairs]
Out[32]: 
[('The first chunk of text ', ('123', '25%')),
 (' The Second chunk of text ', ('456', '50%')),
 (' The third chunk of text ', ('789', '75%')),
 (' The fourth chunk of text ', ('101', '100%'))]
```

---

Of course you can also put this in a loop, which is probably a bit more readable, and all in all more appropriate if you want to print the values:

```
iterator = iter(data[0].splitlines())
for text in iterator:
    stats = next(iterator)
    digit, percent = re.search(r"(\d+).*\((\d+%).*\)", stats).groups()
    print("{:<30} {:>5} {:>5}".format(text.strip(), digit, percent))
```

Output:

```
The first chunk of text          123   25%
The Second chunk of text         456   50%
The third chunk of text          789   75%
The fourth chunk of text         101  100%
```

---

Update: About that `ValueError: not enough values to unpack`: It seems like your list might have an odd number of elements, maybe caused by malformed data, or there is a single empty line at the end of the document. In this case, my solution would yield similar problems, but those could by fixed by e.g. trimming the loaded data to an even number of lines.

Comment: Why the nested comprehension? Why not just `[(A, *re.findall(r'\d+', B)) for A, B in pairs]`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good, point. But that only works with newer versions, right? At least it did not work with the 3.4 I have here right now.

Comment: Odd, but I still don't think that wrapping it in another loop will do the right thing.